# Simple local tunneling proxy that relays requests to a list of external proxies

Tags: python, proxy, tunneling

I'm new here!

And I'm stuck, unfortunately.

I need a single proxy accessible under IP:Port for scraping activities to bypass cloudflare firewall, that can be entered in a browser. Internally, it should relay/tunnel the request, each time the page is reloaded, unchanged to another proxy randomly selected from a list. The proxies on the list do not need login handling. So it 'should' be quite simple to implement. Unfortunately I can't seem to implement it with my preferred language PHP and I'm a absolutely beginner in Python. I wrote (and built from snippets) the following code, it starts without errors, and I can connect to the local python-proxy (according to wget -v output), but unfortunately nothing happens after that. Except a timeout. I tried it on Windows (firewall disabled) and on Debian. The external proxies tested ok too.

Can someone please help me out with this? Am I missing anything obvious as a bloody python beginner?
Or does anyone already know of a simple tunneling proxy script that does what I need (relaying to rotating proxies)? I also would like to add, once the connection works, a mysql query that randomly queries me a proxy from the database, so it should be customizable.

Or is that the completely wrong approach?

Thank You!

```
import socket
import socketserver
import select
import itertools

# proxylist
PROXY_LIST = ['xxx.xxx.xxx.220:3128', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.22:3128', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.105:3128']
proxy_pool = itertools.cycle(PROXY_LIST)

class ThreadingTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

class HTTPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.request.recv(4096).strip()
        proxy = next(proxy_pool)
        hostname, port = proxy.split(':') 
        remote = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        remote.connect(("xxx.xxx.xxx.22", 3128))  # for testing a static proxy, not from above list
        remote.send(data)

        inputs = [self.request, remote]
        while True:
            readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, [], inputs, 60)
            if not readable and not writable and not exceptional:
                break

            for s in readable:
                if s is remote:
                    out = self.request
                else:
                    out = remote
                data = s.recv(4096)
                if data:
                    out.send(data)

            for s in exceptional:
                inputs.remove(s)
                s.close()

        remote.close()
        self.request.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ThreadingTCPServer(('localhost', 3128), HTTPRequestHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

```
wget -v google.de -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=127.0.0.1:3128
```

It connects to the proxy. But respond timeouts. In the moment I kill the script I get the following message:

```
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 56714)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 691, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "xxx\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "xxx\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 755, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "xxx\Test\test.py", line 36, in handle
    data = s.recv(4096)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: One of your problems is that you include `self.request` in your `inputs` list, but you've already read all the data from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can simplify your code a bit by using the [`selectors`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html) module:

```
import selectors
import socket
import socketserver
import itertools

# proxylist
PROXY_LIST = ['172.23.0.2:8888', '172.23.0.3:8888', '172.23.0.4:8888']
proxy_pool = itertools.cycle(PROXY_LIST)

class ThreadingTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

class HTTPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        proxy = next(proxy_pool)
        hostname, port = proxy.split(':') 
        remote = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        remote.connect((hostname, int(port)))

        selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()
        selector.register(self.request, selectors.EVENT_READ)
        selector.register(remote, selectors.EVENT_READ)

        with self.request, remote:
            while True:
                events = selector.select()
                for key, _ in events:
                    infd = key.fileobj
                    outfd = remote if key.fileobj is self.request else self.request

                    data = infd.recv(1024)
                    if not data:
                        break

                    outfd.send(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ThreadingTCPServer(('localhost', 3128), HTTPRequestHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

Using this code, I can run `curl -x localhost:3128 example.com` and it will successfully fetch the remote url, cycling through the list of proxies for each request.

Comment: Your modified code works great in curl! Thank you! That drove me crazy :)

But when you put the proxy in the browser (Chrome), there is no rotation of proxies. The same one is always used. Is this a browser thing, or could you implement this in the code? Maybe the connection must be closed after each request? Is that even possible at this point if you have HTTPS targets? Or perhaps an browser addon to modify headers?
Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer because of my low reputation

Comment: If I configure a browser to use the above python code as an HTTP proxy, it rotates through the proxy list as expected. If a browser is keeping the connection open, that would continue to use the same proxy, because the proxy rotates *per connection*, not per request. To implement a per-request proxy would require implementing an actual HTTP proxy rather than a simple socket proxy.

Comment: Thats right, for different connections it rotates through the proxies. Would it be hard to modify the script to a actual HTTP proxy to rotate per-request? Is there a already usable, but lightweight scipt out there? Or do you have some hint for me, so I don't have to start from scratch?

Comment: You could probably put something together on top of Python's [`http.server` module](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/http.server.html). You can find some examples online, e.g. [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-build-a-super-simple-http-proxy-in-python-in-just-17-lines-of-code-a1a09192be00).